# Xpages: How to toggle searchClear glypicon from search field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

My Xpage has a Bootstrap style search field. When the user types something in the search field I want the clear glypicon to appear, allowing the user to clear the search field and reset the view.

I found some code to do this but am unable to integrate it into my Xpages app. When I try to run this and enter text into the field, Chrome throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
'toLowerCase' of undefined

My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/cc_CommonSearchBar.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:div style="width:300px" styleClass="btn-group">
        <xp:div styleClass="input-group add-on">
            <xp:inputText styleClass="input-medium search-query"
                id="searchinput" type="text">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Search"></xp:attr>
                </xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onkeyup" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var srcClr = XSP.getElementById("#{id:searchclear}");
srcClr.toggle(Boolean($(this).val()));
$(".searchclear").toggle(Boolean($(".searchinput").val()));
$(".searchclear").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.searchinput').val('').focus();
    $(this).hide();
});]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler></xp:inputText>
            <xp:span id="searchclear"
                styleClass="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
            </xp:span>
            <xp:div styleClass="input-group-btn">
                <xp:button styleClass="btn btn-default" type="submit"
                    style="height:34px">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" />
                </xp:button>
            </xp:div>
        </xp:div>
            </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

With Frank's answer below I was able to get this to almost work. My only problem now is a bootstrap issue; the reset x appears over the search button. But I almost have it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/cc_CommonSearchBar.css" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:300px">
        <!--        <div class="btn-group">-->
        <input id="searchinput" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search for..." />
        <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" />
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchinput").keyup(function(){ 
        $("#searchclear").toggle(Boolean(this.value));
    });
        $("#searchclear").toggle(Boolean($("#searchinput").val()));
        $("#searchclear").click(function(){
            $("#searchinput").val("").focus();
            $("#searchclear").hide();
        }); 
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to identify where exactly it is going wrong.
You are calling $(".searchinput").val(), but in your code there is no element with a class 'searchinput'.
Either add 'searchinput' class to the search box.

```
<xp:inputText styleClass="searchinput input-medium search-query"
                id="searchinput" type="text">
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Frank, this got me going and I was able to fix the CSJS. I just have a slight positioning problem now, which I should be able to fix or I can ask another question on SO.